# Display the result in group

Tags: linux, grep

I just need help and wanted to know if what I want is possible. Here's my file
looks like

```
COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN3
--------------------------------------------
A=dog   |  B=354  |  C=343
A=cat   |  B=435  |  B=334
C=324   |  A=cow  |  A=pig
```

Sometimes, I need to filter similar pattern on specific field and display it on
my screen. Example

```sh
grep -Po 'A=(\w+)' test.txt
```

Then I will get

```
A=dog
A=cat
A=bird
A=cow
A=pig
```

But, what I would like to ask is if possible to display another column and show
it beside the first column, here's my example to make it clear

```
A=dog     B=354
A=cat     B=435
A=bird    B=334
A=cow
A=pig
```

Or sometimes, I want to display 3-columns with their respective group. Is this
doable with 'Grep' alone?

Comment: no. grep's job is to find things, not make pretty charts on your screen.

Comment: Where does the `bird` come from? And also, do you mean having the next column if `A=...` is in first column / nothing if `A=...` is in 2nd or 3rd row?

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share what I did after few hours of search and found no easy solution:

**$ grep -Po 'A=(\w+)' test.txt > a.txt

$ grep -Po 'B=(\d+)' test.txt > b.txt

$ pr -mtS a.txt b.txt**

That's it :)

You may also save this in .csv

**$ pr -mts: a.txt b.txt > combine.csv**

*Note: the colon ":" is your delimeter.

Comment: Note that this will scan the file several times. If you want to do it in one pass, look into `sed`, or write a utility in a scripting language like Perl.